# How to optimize custom product collection?

Tags: magento-1.7, product-collection, custom-collection

Actually i want to optimize my store. It takes 5 to 6s. I m using ready theme from theme forest. According to theme m doing some of customization according my requirements which i needed. ON this theme Already displayed new products collection and also sales collection. Now i want to load 2 more collection according to attributes.

So issue is on homepage product collection is load 4 times. If collection is load two times on homepage store will be load within 2s for now. For now i optimize some how my store but still will takes times to load within 4.5 to 5s because of product collection.

I am trying to get product collection by attribute. below code is working perfectly. It takes too much time to load. That's why my store is working too much slow. If i removed this code my store is load within 2 to 2.5s.

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('popular_walldecal', array('eq' => 1))
    ->setPageSize(8);

$_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count();

foreach ($_productCollection as $product):
    $_product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($product->getID());
endforeach;
```

I have tried above code. If product collection loads within in ms. It will be affect on my store to page loading issue.

In above code i need to load again

```
$_product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($product->getID());
```

Otherwise i can't get all product data.

Can you help me to resolve out this issue? How to optimize this code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your issue?

Comment: Not now. No one code is optimize collection.

Comment: Perhaps you can update your question with some extra information or what you've tried. With extra info we can helpt you further\

Answer (score 6):

So let's go trough this line by line

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('popular_walldecal', array('eq' => 1))
    ->setPageSize(8);
```

Perfect, no need to change this. Just make sure you have the *flat product data* enabled under `System > Configuration > Use Flat Catalog Product` and the attribute *popular_walldecal* settings `Use in product listing` set to *yes*

```
$_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count();
```

Loads the whole collection, I suggest using `getSize()` instead of `count` since the first doesn't load the collection.

```
foreach ($_productCollection as $product):
    $_product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($product->getID());
endforeach;
```

Now here's the real issue. The collection just executes one query over one table (*catalog_flat_product_[id]*) but loading the product model in the loop executes a whole bunch of queries per iteration. It's better to add the required data to the collection.

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
   ->addAttributeToFilter('popular_walldecal', array('eq' => 1))
   ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
   ->setPageSize(8);

$_productCollection->addFinalPrice()
   ->addUrlRewrite();

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection(_productCollection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($_productCollection);
```

This will

- filter by `popular_walldecal`
- add all the attributes in the *catalog_flat_product_[id]* table
- set the page size to 8
- add the final price and url rewrite data for the product url
- filter the collection by visibility in catalog
- filter the collection by status enabled

And now you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

You can try after removing `$_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count();`

I think it loads entire collection again and you are not using it.

Comment: Still it takes same loading time.

Comment: Don't load product again in foreach loop. You can directly refer $product.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's slow because you are loading entire products in a foreach loop. Insted you should select everything you need in a collection. For example:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('popular_walldecal', array('eq' => 1))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
    ->setPageSize(8);

foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) {
    Zend_debug::dump($_product->getData());
}
```

Look at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` class for additional methods.

Comment: Can you tell me to other option to load entire products.

Comment: Don't load product again in foreach loop. You can directly refer $product inside loop. For example, `$product->getName();`

Comment: It does not returns result.

Answer (score 0):

Try to explain you SQL query

Get query string

```
Mage::log($_productCollection->getSelect()->assemble());
//or just print it
```

Then in mysql console (phpmyadmin, navicat) run `EXPLAIN [query]` ([explain doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html))

If query has a lot of JOIN's you need to enable **flat product**, but the most correct way is profiling code with [xhprof](https://github.com/perftools/xhgui) - it show where app spent time (e.g. foreach'ing thousand of attribute options)